# Count sorting in vector

Tags: sorting, vector, count, temp

codes before the line is codes that i get count from each name appear.. then i push the name and count into a new class.. and from the class i try to sort by highest number of count to lowest but having problem..codes after line is sorting part  .. the if part inside for loop was having problem.. any 1 can help me

```
void zzz(vector<indi>a)
    {

    vector<sortName>s;
        bool duplicate = false;
        for(int i=0; i<a.size();i++)
        {
            int c=0;
             duplicate = false;
                for (int k=i-1;k>0;k--)
               {
                   if (a[i].getname() == a[k].getname())
                   {
                       duplicate=true;
                   }

               }
            for(int j=i;j<a.size();j++)
           {
               if(a[i].getname()==a[j].getname() && duplicate==false)
               {
                   c++;
               }
           }
           if (duplicate == false)
           {
    cout<<a[i].getname() <<":" <<c <<" "<<endl;

          s.push_back(sortName( a[i].getname(),c));
_______________________________________________________________________    

           }
        }
        for(int i=0;i<s.size();i++)
        {

                    {
    //                    cout<<"before sort "<<i+1<<". ";
                        s[i].sCountshow();
                        cout<<endl;
                    }
        }
        string tempname;
        int tempcount;
        vector<sortName> temp;
        cout<<"running sort";
        for(int i=0;i<s.size();i++)
        {
            for(int j=i+1;j<s.size();j++)
            {
                if(s[i].getsCount()< s[j].getsCount())
                {
                    temp[0]= s[i];
                    s[i]=s[j];
                    s[j]=temp[0];

                    tempname = s[i].getname();
                    tempcount = s[i].getsCount();
                    s[i] = s[j];
                   s.erase(s[i]);
                   s.insert(s.begin()+j,sortName(tempname,tempcount));
                }
                }

            }
    cout<<"end sort";
     for(int i=0;i<s.size();i++)
        {

                    {
                        cout<<"after sort "<<i+1<<". ";
                        s[i].sCountshow();
                        cout<<endl;
                    }
        }
```

Comment: theres no point on having a for in there if you wont do anything on it, just make you if larger that may do

Comment: since i dont really know whats the error you are having (error code and that stuff) i could only recommend you to check this up and modify your "if" like this
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c6s3h5a7.aspx

Comment: ivan can i ask u something...http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/stable_sort

Comment: the example is from smaller to bigger so he use < booloperator?